# Terraform Upgrade from latest version12 to version13

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to upgrade from the Terraform version 12 to the version 13, but I saw that there are some 13 beta versions before the 13.0 can I skip those beta versions for the upgrade?
Would it make any difference and save some possible errors or bugs in that beta version?

Comment: There are helper commands (i.e., `0.13upgrade`), so use them. Unless you want to use the beta version, you can use any other non-beta 0.13 version. More info here: https://www.terraform.io/language/v1.1.x/upgrade-guides/0-13#upgrading-to-terraform-v0-13.

Comment: that is very helpful Marko. saw that the terraform init command to start with the new version is giving the generic error: Error: Failed to decode current backend config. The backend configuration created by most recent run of terraform init
could not be decoded: unsupported attribute "lock_table". The configuration
may have been initialized by an earlier version that used an incompatible
configuration structure. Run "terraform init -reconfigure" to force
re-initialization of the backend.
 A possible solution would be terraform init --reconfigure would it break the state or the system?